# SCSS/CSS - Decrement zindex value for nonsibling elements

Tags: css, sass

I currently have the following HTML in a React Component and i need to set the `z-index` on the `<header>`'s in order for their tooltips to overlap the content below correctly. The Header in each section needs to have its `z-index` higher than the header in the next section.

I am currently achieving this via inline styles but appreciate this is not very scalable. I was wondering if there was a way i could do this via SCSS/CSS rather than inline styles?

```
<section>
  <header style={{zIndex: 3}}></header>
</section>
<section>
  <header style={{zIndex: 2}}></header>
</section>
<section>
  <header style={{zIndex: 1}}></header>
</section>
<section>
  <header style={{zIndex: 0}}></header>
</section>
```

Thanks

Comment: So your tooltips appears more than 1 at a time? You can do a loop and achieve this

Comment: _“but appreciate this is not very scalable”_ - how so? At that point I’d assume you know how many such sections you will have, whereas your CSS or SCSS probably won’t know about that - so with those you could at most generate “enough” rules upfront. Of course you could create say one or two dozen rules with a loop in SCSS easily, that use `:nth-child()` to target the sections first and then the header elements inside. (I assume it doesn’t really matter whether the z-index values would be actually from 3 to 0 for your given example, or if it was 12 to 9 instead?)

Comment: No there is only one tooltip at a time, but the tooltip is mounted under header, but needs to display above section.

Comment: Or you simply let a small JS function run over all those sections, and set the z-index then. (Assuming the tooltips are based on some JS functionality as well, so they won’t function before any scripts are run in the first place …?)

Comment: @CBroe i was thinking of using `nth-child()` and yes I do currently know how many sections I have, I was just wondering if there was a way for it to automatically decrement the z-index for each new one added if we decided to add another.

Comment: No, I don’t think there is any such automatism. But you don’t need the z-indexes exactly as in your given example, right? Whether these were actually 3, 2, 1, 0, or 20, 19, 18, 17, would not change anything about how this works, even if there are only 4 sections like in your example. So if you started with an automatically generated set of “enough” rules, from `:nth-child(1) { z-index:20; }` to `:nth-child(20) { z-index:1; }`, this would still work for _up to_ 20 sections in any case.

Comment: You are exactly right that the `z-index` numbers dont matter as long as they decrement, Do you know how i might achieve that in the selector structure i outlined above?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178458/discussion-between-jack-wilkinson-and-cbroe).